# ng-bootstrap Carousel hide pagination indicators, 'showNavigationIndicators' does not exist on type 'NgbCarouselConfig'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to hide carousel using

```
     <ngb-carousel   #ngbCarouselid="ngbCarousel" [showNavigationIndicators]="false" [interval]="false" [wrap]="false" *ngIf="numReceipts() > 0" class="center-block no-indicators image-view">
```

but its not recognizing the `[showNavigationIndicators].`

Error which I am getting, just because of 'showNavigationIndicatiors'

```
core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'showNavigationIndicators' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-carousel'.
1. If 'ngb-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'showNavigationIndicators' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<div class="imgCarousel">

      <ngb-carousel   #ngbCarouselid="ngbCarousel" [ERROR ->][showNavigationIndicators]="false" [interval]="false" [wrap]="false" *ngIf="numReceipts() > 0" class="): ng:///AccountsModule/ReceiptPreviewComponent.html@30:51
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'showNavigationIndicators' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-carousel'.
1. If 'ngb-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'showNavigationIndicators' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<div class="imgCaro
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working but you cannot see it because you didn't include bootstrap css.

You can try on stackblitz by setting `index.html` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>ng-bootstrap demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but in actual project its not recognizing the showNavigationIndicators although its recognizing the config.interval/wrap/keyboard

Comment: Make sure you imported `NgbModule.forRoot()` in the app module and in the component provide the config: `providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]`

Comment: its there but still giving me issue. I edited the question with my error

Comment: Are you trying to hide arrows or indicators?

Comment: Yeah, but not with css hide property

Comment: Yeah I understand, but which one you want to hide, or both of them?

Comment: @SahilKkr From `verify that it is part of this module.` I understand that it isn't included in the module. Please double check or show us the app.module

Comment: from app.module.ts   
import { NgbModule, NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
imports[
    NgbModule.forRoot(),]

Comment: import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
imports[ NgbModule]

Comment: hows it possible its recognizing the wrap property but showNavigationIndicators

Comment: @LXhelili I already imported it, I want hide indicators but its not recognizing both

Comment: is it imported as I said without static forRoot() method and you just need to import NgbModule not NgbCarouselConfig

Comment: I tried that too, dont know what mistake I am doing, but I used   @ViewChild('carousel') carousel: NgbCarousel; to use carousel in my component

Comment: Checkout how I implemented it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8y9fnn

Comment: and for you case instead of @ViewChild('carousel') carousel: NgbCarousel; as I see in template you need to change it to @ViewChild('ngbCarouselid') carousel: NgbCarousel;

Comment: @LXhelili my apologies for late reply, it didnt give any notification for your reply, I tried your solution but it didn't work too, I am getting same error 
using .......
 @ViewChild('ngbCarouselid') carousel: NgbCarousel;

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue as you. The error message is

```
Property *'showNavigationArrows' does not exist on type 'NgbCarouselConfig'.*
```

I haven't found the solution but I think is it regarding ng-boostrap version that we use.

In the imported node_model, inside the carousel-config.d.ts, the source code in my local:

```
export declare class NgbCarouselConfig {
    interval: number;
    wrap: boolean;
    keyboard: boolean;
}
```

However, when I check the github, the source code is as below:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Configuration service for the NgbCarousel component.
 * You can inject this service, typically in your root component, and customize the values of its properties in
 * order to provide default values for all the carousels used in the application.
 */
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class NgbCarouselConfig {
  interval = 5000;
  wrap = true;
  keyboard = true;
  pauseOnHover = true;
  showNavigationArrows = true;
  showNavigationIndicators = true;
}
```

Note that this function it's available in carousel from 2.2.0 only. So check your local version of ng-bootstrap.

Comment: I am using ng-bootsrap 1.0.4 version and cant update with 2 because its compatible with Angular6

Comment: Our project uses Angular 5,  and I am also trying to update the ng-bootstrap but no luck. I think we should use another way to make the carousel. I am googling all day but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: I used another approach. ngIf array.length> 1 then use carousel if array.length then show one image only